# Not able to compile flutter app in iOS because of image_picker_ios

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am compiling my application in iOS and am getting the following error

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Semantic Issue (Xcode): Unknown type name 'FLTMaxSize'
/Users/vikkasmiittal/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_ios-0.8.5/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin_Te
st.h:36:39

Semantic Issue (Xcode): Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/vikkasmiittal/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_ios-0.8.5/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin_Te
st.h:36:0

Semantic Issue (Xcode): Cannot find protocol declaration for 'FLTImagePickerApi'
/Users/vikkasmiittal/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_ios-0.8.5/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin_Te
st.h:53:36

Parse Issue (Xcode): Could not build module 'image_picker_ios'
/Users/vikkasmiittal/Developer/flutterProj/sportsgiri/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:39:8

a) This plugin works absolutely fine in Android
b) Flutter doctor does not show any error
c) Image picker version that I am using is 0.8.5+3 (the latest one)

Can any one please help me resolving this issue!!

Comment: Had the same problem. The project was still using Obj-C, after converting it to Swift it worked.

Comment: you solved it??

Comment: any update on this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `flutter pub upgrade` after editing the package version in the pubspec.yml.

Deleting Pods, Podfile.lock, running `pod install` and so on is not enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try cleanup of pods and reinstall.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: An answer should not ask him/her to **try** something. If you want to do so, leave a comment.

Comment: I tried - did not help.

I also tried removing the ios folder and regenerating it with 
flutter create -i swift .

And then freshly install the pods - but it still did not help